# Protractor test fail on iPad using sauceLabs

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e, saucelabs, e2e-testing

I'm not able to run my protractor test using the iPad. The desktop browser tests are working fine. Here is my configuration:

```
exports.config = {

  sauceUser: "xxx",
  sauceKey: "xxx",

  allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
  specs: [
  'smoke.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'appium-version': '',
    platformName: 'iOS',
    platformVersion: '8.1',
    deviceName: 'iPad Simulator',
    browserName: 'safari'
  },


  framework: 'jasmine',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000
  }
};
```

And here is the output:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: The Sauce VMs failed to start the browser or device
```

Is there something wrong with my capabilites configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corresponding docs for testing iphone/ipad: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/mobile-setup.md#setting-up-protractor-with-appium---iossafari

I would suggest you test using a local device first if sauce doesn't work for you at first try, so you can narrow down the issue (unless you don't have a mac or physical ipad to test with that is).